# How to add datas in a <tr> table in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add some data in the following table structure :

```
<table>
    <tr id = "line_one">
        <!-- datas here -->
    </tr>
    <tr id = "line_two">
        <!-- or data here -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

I already tried in JQuery the following call to .appendTo() :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#line_one").appendTo("<td>test</td>");
    }   
</script>
```

Does anyone has a clue of what happened wrong on this short code ?

Comment: use just append, [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) is used to append TO an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.append()` in your case and not `.appendTo()` .

`.appendTo()` will append `tr` to `td`

```
$("#line_one").append("<td>test</td>");
```

Also

```
$(document).ready(function(){
……… 

});
```

Closing paranthesis missing.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention these but I wrote it correctly in my code, thanks !

Comment: Yeah..I knew that. Just checked

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `append`, not `appendTo`.

As is it, you're appending `#line_one` to a newly created DOM object `<td>test</td>` and just keeping it in memory.

Comment: Thank you Ayman Safadi, like other have said, this is the solution, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `append` instead of `appendTo`

Comment: Thank you for you help kiks73, this works great like Shaunak D anwser !

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#line_one").html("<td>test</td>");
 }   
</script>
```